# parsing new lines with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

When parsing an html doc with BeautifulSoup, sometimes new lines are produced by html code, e.g.

`<div style="line-height:120%;text-align:left;font-size:10pt;"><font style="font-family:inherit;font-size:10pt;"><br></font></div><div style="line-height:120%;text-align:left;font-size:10pt;"><font style="font-family:inherit;font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold;">`

so when I extract text I miss a new line:

```
page = open(fname)
try:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
except:
    sys.exit("cannot parse %s" % fname)
soup.prettify(formatter=lambda s: s.replace(u'\xa0', ' '))

for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
    script.extract()    # rip it out
if not soup.body:
    return
text = soup.body.get_text(separator = ' ')
lines = (clean_str(line) for line in text.splitlines())
chunks = (phrase.strip() for line in lines for phrase in line.split("  "))
text = '\n'.join(chunk for chunk in chunks if chunk)
```

Is there an adjustment I can add, that would break the text into lines correctly?

Comment: Could you add a some sample HTML to your question that recreates the problem?

Comment: Ha, there was html code, but it was processed and showed as new lines! I've commented it to make it visible. So basically, any text separated by that html code shows up on different lines in html, but my python code simply removes it, hence I get no new lines.

Comment: You could try and use `for text in soup.strings:` to iterate over each text block but a `<br>` on its own will probably still get missed.